# Sorting a list by keeping track of the swapped indices for reshaping a second list

Tags: python, sorting, nested-lists

I have a list with numbers:

```
S = [12, 5, 7, 100, 50]
```

and an associate list of lists:

```
AS = [['G'], ['W'], ['F'], ['N'], ['L']]
```

and I would like to sort S list, such that the associate list is also modified accordingly.
Output:

```
SortedS = [5, 7, 12, 50, 100]
modifiedAS = [['W'], ['F'], ['G'], ['L'], ['N']]
```

Any help with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
S = [12, 5, 7, 100, 50]
AS = [['G'], ['W'], ['F'], ['N'], ['L']]

zipped_sorted_lists = sorted(zip(S, AS), key=lambda i: i[0])
S_sorted, AS_sorted = zip(*zipped_sorted_lists)

print(S_sorted)
print(AS_sorted)
```

Console output:

```
(5, 7, 12, 50, 100)
(['W'], ['F'], ['G'], ['L'], ['N'])
```

Comment: you dont need a key in your sort `zip(*sorted(zip(S,AS)))` is enough, the sorting by default happens on the first element

Comment: That's true, based on how tuples are sorted, and probably marginally more efficient not to include it. But for readability/making it clear what the code is trying to do, it may be desirable to include the `key` argument. Depends on your priorities.

Comment: make sense, I guess it would be better if you can explain unpacking using `*`, that does most of the heavy lifting here

Answer (score 0):

```
Z = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(S,AS))]
```

herer we go. Z will be your sorted AS list by the sorting of the S list